# Adding another CI application?

Tags: add-on-development, codeigniter

I need to grab a CSV version of one of my channel entries and upload it to an FTP server. I also need to grab some images, which are part of the channel entries, and rename them, etc.

I have already created a template that renders the CSV I need. Now, I need to do all that FTP and image processing stuff. The process could be triggered by adding or editing a Channel entry -- or I could just run this via a cron at some set interval.

How should I deal with this process? Should I build some sort of addon? Or should I create a separate CI application? I'm actually not sure how to add another CI application to the current EE/CI setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, [creating an extension](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html) would be the right way to do it.

The hook to be used will be entry_submission_end, the extension setting should contain remote host, post, path - and template name or URL of file to upload.

You can use [CI FTP library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html) in your add-on.

Quick search does not find anything that would do even something similar - so the whole community would benefit if you develop it and make public :)

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I'm now worried about hooking into `entry_submission_end`. The process is such that I would need to do this for pretty much ALL channel entries (not just the current one). And due to the image processing stuff (e.g. renaming, converting to JPG, etc.), that could take a long time. Maybe a separate application to handle this would be better as it won't interfere with adding/editing Channel entries? If so, how do I add another application?

Comment: Then I would create a module, add an action in it and run it pericodically by requesting URL like `http://site.com/?ACT=XX` via CRON (where XX is action ID)